# How to implement a sub-application within the main application of sveltkit?

Tags: routes, svelte, sveltekit

I would like to create a new sub-app (for generating invoices) folder within the main app folder. The main app will handle the user authentication, whereas the sub-app (invoice app) will be handling its own functions. It will have separate routes, components, styles, and statics.

There are a couple of approaches I thought of

All the files, folders, and codes are in the main folder itself. This will make the code very big and difficult to separate and maintain especially if a new app is to be added.

Separate app folder within the main folder which has its own src folder, styles, static files, and others. It will also maintain its separate dependency.

Are there any other methods for achieving this?

Note: Important question, how to route to the sub-application folder? I have seen "routify" to define the custom routing path to define the sub-app folder. Is this the only way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest separation would be

- Having both applications as separate SvelteKit projects, on their separate Git repositories
- Any shared code between the applications would go to a library module, its own NPM project
- Both applications run on their own servers, virtual servers or at least different Vite web server port
- Have a reverse proxy web server (Caddy, Nginx, etc.) that routes HTTP requests to different applications based on URL

[Here is an example how we route multiple SvelteKit applications from the same Caddy configuration file](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/proxy-server/blob/master/Caddyfile), although it is too complex for a simple example as it also introduces Docker to the hosting mix.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have looked at PNPM to create a mono-repo for the code separation and creation of a shared library for the components and utilities.

Answer (score 2):

The downside of a file-based router is that the routes are all in one routes folder.

You might want to look into: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#advanced-layouts
because SvelteKit does have some grouping capabilities:

```
|- src/routes/
|  |- (invoices)/
|  |  |- +layout.svelte
|  |  |- lib/
|  |  |  |- fetchInvoive.ts
|  |  |
|  |  |- invoices/
|  |     |- page.svelte
|  |
|  |- (main)/
|  |  |- +layout.svelte
```

I'd probably won't put the `fetchInvoice.ts` inside the routes folder but create a src/invoices folder with a $invoices [alias](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#alias)

Generating truly separate apps might be possible, but it's going against the grain and i don't think it's worth the hassle.

Depending on your use-case an other option could be to create a shared library that provides some components and utilities for authentication and use that library in different SvelteKit apps on multiple (sub)domains.